# Connect backend and frontend

Tags: laravel, api, backend

How to connect frontend to backend?

The site was Laravel 5.7 + VUE. Now was completely written from scratch in JS frontend (self-written).

I. e. it is necessary to leave the old backend (Laravel 5.7) + API and connect the new frontend to it.

As I understand it, you need to rewrite the old backend for a new frontend or not?

New frontend only. The task is to connect the old backend and API to the new frontend.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to write a new backend to replace the frontend.

Comment: How to connect the new frontend with the old backend?

Comment: Look at the available routes in your application. You can post data from your frontend (for example in vue, with [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)) to your backend. Instead of using an html `form` with an `action` attribute, you can now send requests to the backend without leaving the page. [Here is a pretty nice boilerplate for a Vue SPA](https://github.com/cretueusebiu/laravel-vue-spa)

Comment: run `php artisan route:list` on your laravel project and there you see your backend API. Build your new frontend on top of that

Comment: Was the old frontend using ajax to get its data or was the data getting passed as props to the components?

Comment: Before use props (VUE). Now want use ajax.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to rewrite your backend, in fact a would try to leave it as it is, and just try to connect new frontend with existing backend API (endpoints). Or is there any specific reason for changing the backenend codebase?

Answer (score 0):

VUE is a Javascript frontend framework and Laravel is a framework for PHP so you do not need to rewrite the backend. What you need to do is configure your frontend to match the
Laravel codebase in the backend.